# Working with Facebook PHP SDK: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost dat

Tags: php, facebook, api, curl, sdk

I had a look at several stackoverflow posts about this error message, but none of them worked for me.

I want to upload a photo to facebook:

```
public function uploadPhoto($path){
    $photoSettings = array(
        'access_token'=> $this->facebook->getAccessToken(),
        'name' => 'uploaded foto',
        'source' => '@' . realpath($path)
    );

    $photo = $this->facebook->api('me/photos','POST',$photoSettings);
}
```

When i call this function, i get the following error message:

Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data

I am 100% sure that the image i want to upload exists (and the path is correct).

This is my facebook initialization: (fileUpload is true)

```
$this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => $this->config['appId'],
          'secret' => $this->config['appSecret'],
          'fileUpload' => true,
          'cookie' => true
    ));
```

I really don't understand why i get that error because my code seems to be correct. Do you think there could be a problem with my server / the server's cURL configuration? I dont know much about cURL.

I hope you can help me! I am looking forward for your answers :-)

Greetings,
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

Your `realpath($path)` is not pointing to the actual server image location. If `$path` is the complete path of the image, then use `'source' => '@' . $path` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
I kept getting “CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data” 

Here is my working code for uploading a photo from the same directory as the PHP page communicating with   Facebook:
$facebook    =  new Facebook(array(
'appId'      =>'*****',
'secret'     =>'*******',
'fileUpload' => true,
'cookie'     => true
));
 $user  =   $facebook ->getUser();
 if($user) 
 {  
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array(
    'message' => 'TEst from App.',
    'image' => '@' . realpath('awesome.jpeg')
);
try {
    $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo "ERROR: " . $e;
}

 }
```